# How to change the order of columns and plot images side by side with seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

I have a dataset contains the answers from a multiple-choice test. The test includes 24 exam codes, each exam code has 50 key answers(A,B,C,D for 50 questions). Below is a corner of it, you can access the whole thing with the link I put at the end.

[image]

I want to count the number of each answer (ABCD) in each exam code. Here I plotted 2 exam codes like this:

[image]

How can I plot them side by side and change the order of answers in Python? I want the order of columns is "ABCD". (I've tried using plt.subplot, sns.factorplot but I keep getting errors).

Thank you.

Data link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dYuHEKTJHnVO_dUOyGBIYfFvkZIunLyE/view?usp=sharing

Edition 1: I'm able to plot orderly with the below code.

```
sns.catplot(x = 'code0', data = test, kind = "count", order = ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `melt` the dataframe to [long form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) and then use the variable name for `catplot`'s `col=` parameter.  `col_wrap` tell how many columns to create before starting a new row.  `height=` controls the height of the individual subplots.  `aspect=` is the ratio between the subplot's width and height.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([*'ABCD'], size=(50, 24)),
                    columns=[f'code{i}' for i in range(24)])
g = sns.catplot(data=test.melt(var_name='code'), x='value', col='code', col_wrap=6,
                order=["A", "B", "C", "D"], kind='count',
                sharex=False, height=2, aspect=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot from melted dataframe]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, it works perfectly! I manually collected the data in a excel file, exported as a csv and created the frame with pd.read_csv.